# Spring Batch -@BeforeStep not getting invoked in ClassifierCompositeItemWriter

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-batch

The method is not called with the @BeforeStep decorator that calls the ClassifierCompositeItemWriter, is there a workaround?

**step**

```
     @Bean
            public Step step2(ItemStreamReader <ValidateCandidateRentDto> itemValidateCandidateRentDtoReader,
                              ValidateCandidateRentProcess 

itemValidateCandidateRentDtoProcess,ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<ValidateCandidateRentDto> classifierCompositeItemWriter) throws Exception {
    
            return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2")
                    .<ValidateCandidateRentDto, ValidateCandidateRentDto>chunk(100)
                    .reader(itemValidateCandidateRentDtoReader)
                    .processor(itemValidateCandidateRentDtoProcess)
                    .writer(classifierCompositeItemWriter)
                    .build();
        }
```

**ClassifierCompositeItemWriter**

```
@Bean
    public ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<ValidateCandidateRentDto> classifierCompositeItemWriter(UpdateCandidateRentWriter itemUpdateCandidateRentDtoWriter, ValidateCandidateRentWriter itemValidateCandidateRentDtoWriter) throws Exception {
        ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<ValidateCandidateRentDto> classifierCompositeItemWriter = new ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<>();
        classifierCompositeItemWriter.setClassifier(new CandidateClassifier(itemUpdateCandidateRentDtoWriter,itemValidateCandidateRentDtoWriter));
        return classifierCompositeItemWriter;
    }
```

**writer**

```
public class ValidateCandidateRentWriter implements ItemWriter<ValidateCandidateRentDto> {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ValidateCandidateRentWriter.class);

    @Autowired
    private CirCanRepRepository cirCanRepRepository;

    private StepExecution stepExecution;
    @BeforeStep
    public void before(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.stepExecution=stepExecution;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends ValidateCandidateRentDto> list) throws Exception {
        this.stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("ValidateCandidatesRentDto",list);
    }
}
```

**log**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at cl.ccla.reprogramacion.job.ValidateCandidateRentWriter.write(ValidateCandidateRentWriter.java:31) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.write(ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.java:69) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ValidateCandidateRentWriter` is not getting proxied as a `StepExecutionListener`. You need to declare it as a bean in your application context so that Spring (Batch) introspects the `@BeforeStep` method and creates a proxy for it.

Another option is to make this component implement `StepExecutionListener` and register it explicitly in the step definition.

Please check the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/step.html#stepExecutionListener) for more details about this feature.